# Compare elements of two lists in JSP and hide fields based on comparison

Tags: java, list, jsp, arraylist, collections

I am having two lists. Both are having string messages. List A is having all messages, List B is having few messages which are present in list A.
I am iterating list A and list B. Trying to compare and print messages based on comparison. If list message is present in both lists I am hiding it else displaying it. The custom list gives the key which is passed to method to retrieve the full message. Both the messages in list are same yet the comparison is not working as expected. Please suggest.

**Code snippet below:**

```
           for(String testMsg:testPages.get(testAlertPage)){

                for(int i=0; i < customList.size(); i++){ 
                    if(testMsg.equals(retrieve(customList.get(i)))){

                        %>
                        <p class="paragraph" style="display:none"><%=testMsg %></p><br>
                   <%                   
                    }else{
                    %>
                        <p><%=testMsg %></p><br>
                   <%                              
                    }
                    }

                %>

            }
```

Comment: Assuming the strings have the _exact_ same contents then instead of iterating yourself you could do `if(customList.contains(testMsg))` which effectively is the same. If the content isn't the same then this wouldn't work but neither would `equals()` (`equalsIgnoreCase()` might work if case is the only difference). Besides that, why are you even rendering the message with display:none if you want to hide it anyway?

Comment: Btw, "But somehow the comparison is not working properly as expected." - remember that we can't guess what exactly you expect and what happens instead so please add that information to your question ideally accompanied by some examples.

Answer (score 1):

With these nested loops, you compare each message in the first list against **all** the messages in `customList`, and display them if the message differs from **any** element there. Instead, for each message, you should only display it if it exists in `customList`:

```
<%
for (String testMsg : testPages.get(testAlertPage)) {
    if (customList.contains(testMsg) { 
 %>
     <p class="paragraph" style="display:none"><%=testMsg %></p><br>
<%                   
    } else {
%>
    <p><%=testMsg %></p><br>
<%
    }
%>
```

**Note:** You should probably replace `customList` with a `Set` for better performance.

Comment: I agree with you. Also I had tried same way before. But the problem is my list is having keys. And I pass those keys to a method and then I get complete message which I am comparing with other list element. Due to this reason I am using two for loops. After the iteration of custom list I get the key which is used to retrieve the complete message. code snippet Below:  if(testMsg.equals(retrieveMsg(customList.get(i)))){         Please suggest any possible way.